# Converting HTML formatted text to regular text in ColdFusion 9

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

An application consists of Flex as front end, ColdFusion 9 as middle tier and MySQL 5 as the back end.

A MySQL table contains some fields which contain HTML formatting. So, if a field has value string "Test Record" it is stored as 
`<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Test Record<FONT SIZE="8"></FONT></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>`
in the MySQL table

Now, this field's value is being printed in a PDF document as

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" filename="#report_filename_format#" orientation="landscape"
overwrite="yes"
marginbottom="0" marginleft="0" marginright="0" margintop="0"
pagetype="legal">


<tr>
<td width="20%" style="background-color:##CCCCCC; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; vertical-align:top;">
Value
</td>
<td width="80%">#printrecord.field_value#</td>
</tr>
```

Since, the field value is stored with HTML formatting, the space taken is more and there is no
control about the printed text's font type and font size.

1. Is there any function in ColdFusion 9 which can convert the field's value to a regular text (without the HTML formatting) so that if "Test Record" would print the same regardless of whether it was stored as font size 10 or font size 30?
2. I am thinking of one way is to get the record being printed in a Flex application, use field.text property of a TextArea control (in Flex) 
   to convert to regular text, then pass the converted value to ColdFusion for printing in the PDF document. Are there other better options?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the "solution" is quite simple:

```
<cfscript>
  data   = '<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="##0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Test Record<FONT SIZE="8"></FONT></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>';
  regex  = "<(.|\n)*?>";
  result = reReplaceNoCase(data, regex, "", "all");

  writeOutput(result);
</cfscript>
```

I've added an addition hash tag to the HTML for my example to avoid syntax errors. From what you have said, I assume this will be fetched by a db query anyway.

Also (nitpicking now!) I would suggest updating the db with the new values and get rid of the in-line styling in favour of CSS if you can ;-)

Comment: Using `NoCase` is redundant when there is no case in the regex, and using `<(.|\n)*?>` is inefficient. Better to use `<[^>]*>` if doing it this method. (Though I probably wouldn't do it this way; no guarantee of valid HTML.)

Comment: The idea, I believe, was to remove the HTML so the data is formatted then update the database with these values. So this is a run once never again job. I completely agree that regular expressions are no good with (irregular) HTML, but it seemed the simplest solution for the op.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not handle escaped characters such as `&nbsp;`, or `&lt;`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use a HTML parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

This would be particularly recommended if the HTML is unpredictable or might not be valid, since it will handle this in the same way as a browser (whereas a regex is simply pattern matching; it doesn't actually know what is/isn't a tag).

```
<cfset data = '<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="##0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Test Record<FONT SIZE="8"></FONT></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>' />

<cfset jsoup = createObject('java','org.jsoup.Jsoup') />

<cfset text = jsoup.parse(data).text() />

<cfdump var=#text# />
```

The jsoup line can be performed once and stored in, e.g. the Application scope. Also, you need the jsoup jar to make it work - for CF9, you'll need to copy it into your {coldfusion}/lib directory then restart the server.